# SQL and Rails complex query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm building a Rails application for to manage a services company scheduling.

For the scope of this question, the model structure is:

> Client Has Many Contracts
>
> Contracts Has Many Services
>
> Workers Has Many Services

In my query i have a worker and a client, and i need to produce a

> @contracts relationship

that match all contracts that have in common the client and the worker.

I've tried in lot of ways, but if i produce recursively the @contracts list via select{} and a loop, i obtain an array that is not an ActiveRecord and it cannot be used in the rails app (for example in erb).

I'm stuck :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the proper `has_many` and `belongs_to` relationships setup, your query would probably look something like this:

```
Contract.joins(services: :worker)
        .where(services: {worker_id: target_worker_id})
        .where(contracts: {client_id: target_client_id}).uniq
```

where `target_worker_id` and `target_client_id` are the worker and clients you wish to filter by.

This query will join `contracts` to the `services` table (because you said "Contracts has many Services"), which also joins the `services` table to the `workers` table (because you said "Workers has many services"). In short, it appears that `services` is a join table, the result of a many-to-many relationship, hence the join clause.

Edit: Note the `.uniq`, which is necessary to ensure only distinct `Contract` objects are loaded. Otherwise, as you experienced, the inner join caused by the `.join` method will essentially create a collection of duplicates.

Let me know if I've misunderstood anything, or if you have additional questions on this answer.

Quick note: You wrote *i obtain an array that is not an ActiveRecord and it cannot be used in the rails app (for example in erb).* I'm not entirely clear what you mean, but any instance variable created in the controller can be used in ERB; it doesn't need to be an active record object. As stated though, I'm not sure if this is what you meant.

Comment: Thank you for the help! The road look promising. But i have a duplication of some contracts in this way, when i have some contracts with more than one service associated at a worker.

Comment: @IdoTraini oh yes I forgot about that. Just add `.uniq` to the end of the query. I'll update the answer in a moment. That will ensure only distinct Contract objects are loaded, no duplicates. The duplication is the result of the inner join caused by the `.join` method.

Comment: @Richter, it's fine. Indeed, i've tried .uniq!, but it give me error, but without the ! it runs. thank you :)

Comment: @IdoTraini Are you running an older version of rails (< Rails 4)? Either way, I usually avoid the bang methods (those with `!`) unless I actually explicitly need them because they usually imply they're modifying the object on which they're called. That might not always be desirable and could lead to strange issues if you're not careful. In this case it probably doesn't matter anyways. Don't forget to accept and upvote helpful answers. Good luck!

Comment: I'm not able to vote for the moment, but i will honor my debt asap ;)

Comment: @IdoTraini Ah yes I believe its 15 pts for upvotes. I appreciate the accept, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :conctracts, inverse_of: client, dependent: :destroy
end

class Contract < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :services
end

class Worker < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :services

end

class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :worker
  belongs_to :contract

  has_many :clients, through: contract

  scope :workers, ->(*w) {
    where(worker_id: w.flatten.compact.uniq)
  }

  scope :contracts, ->(*c) {
    where(contract_id: c.flatten.compact.uniq)
  }
end

workers = Worker.all

clients = Client.join(contracts: {services: worker}).merge(Service.workers(workers))
```

Comment: The OP wrote *i need to produce a @contracts relationship that match all contracts that have in common the client and the worker.* This sounds very much like they want to obtain a collection of `Contract` objects for a given client and worker, not `Client` objects.